# Standard way to pull a specific model from a common view in Django/DRF?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I currently have two models that are essentially the same (inheriting from a base model), but I have problems referring to them from a common view:

**Models:**

```
class BaseModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(...)
    owner = ForeignKey(...)

class Cat(BaseModel):
    ...

class Dog(BaseModel):
    ...
```

**View:**

```
class CommonViewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    @link()
    def set_owner(self, request, pk=None):

        #how do I get Cat or Dog models cleanly here?

        #super fugly/unstable way
        url_path = request.META['PATH_INFO']
        if 'cats' in url_path:
            Cat.objects.get(pk=pk).owner = ...
        elif 'dogs' in url_path:
            Dog.objects.get(pk=pk).owner = ...
```

I can also put the `set_owner` link in separate views, but that feels un-DRY. Thanks in advance for looking into this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the model to use in the `as_view` method of your class:

```
url(r'^cats/my-url/$', CommonViewSet.as_view(model=Cat)),
```

The `ModelViewSet` class inherits from Django's `View` class, so this will set the `model` attribute on the instance of your viewset. You can then use `self.model` to get the right model for the current url.

Comment: Thanks! I'm using router so the model would be set inside the Viewset.